# Use Pandas to find duplicates and unique elements in 2 other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that are created from XML data; they have a list of filenames and path for each file, including some extra metadata. Something like this

```
filename - filepath - meta1 - meta2 - meta3
```

basically each dataframe has files that may have the same name of files in another dataframe, but they will be in different paths. I am trying to compare those 2 dataframes to find out which files are unique across the 2 dataframes, and which filenames are common across the 2 dataframes. I am going to look just at the filename; so if a file is present on both dataframes, even if the path is different, I will count them as duplicate.

I started to look at various Pandas methods and found the `drop_duplicates()` function, which would work for my case, after specifying that I just want to use the `filename` column

```
df_unique = df_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=['filename'])
```

This should return me a dataframe containing only the unique filenames from both the dataframe that has been concatenated. But how do I get the duplicate list?

Example:

```
df1:
filename - filepath - meta1 - meta2 - meta3
test1      c:\tests    ax1      ax2    cv
test2      c:\tests    ax1      ax1    cv
test3      c:\tests    ax2      ax1    cb

df2:
filename - filepath - meta1 - meta2 - meta3
test1      c:\tests2   ax1      ax2    cv
test4      c:\tests2   ax1      ax1    cv
test2      c:\tests2   ax2      ax1    cc
test5      c:\tests2   ax1      ax1    cb

df_unique:
filename - filepath - meta1 - meta2 - meta3
test1      c:\tests    ax1      ax2    cv
test2      c:\tests    ax1      ax1    cv
test3      c:\tests    ax2      ax1    cb
test4      c:\tests2   ax1      ax1    cv
test5      c:\tests2   ax1      ax1    cb

df_duplicates:
test1      c:\tests    ax1      ax2    cv
test2      c:\tests    ax1      ax1    cv
```

So the unique is basically the first instance of any unique filename found in both dataframes, just matching the filename (so if the other fields are different, that is OK
And the duplicate dataframe is the first instance of what is common in the 2 dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge with outer join method an use the indicator left only to right only for unique and both for duplicates

df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['filename'],how="outer",indicator=True)